# Data binding error: property is not defined

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have followed the tutorials for creating a data input form in Nativescript/Angular. However, instead of triggering a console log, the console tells me the property I wish to print out is undefined.

Sample in playground below. The services and appSettings storage functionality have been stripped out.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=6mEiJz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your console.log(), you need to refer to properties and methods inside of your component with `this`

So your log line should be `console.log("Logging in as ", this.name);` because it is referring to a property of your component which is `this` in this instance.